# Proper way to escape and display strings in forms using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, escaping

I have a web form that is accepting information about a book (title, author, description, etc.). I have been using CodeIgniter's active record db class to insert the information, and have **not** escaped the queries because the CodeIgniter documentation claims to do this already (see [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)).

**So here's the problem:** If I a put in a title like "A Boy's Guide To The World" that has an apostrophe in it, it is escaped and inserted properly into the database. However, when I display it in a form like:

```
<input type="text" name="title" <?php if (isset($book)) { echo "value='" . $book->name . "' "; ?> />
```

It will only show "A Boy" as the title. I understand why the apostrophe is breaking, and can think of a number of ways to fix it, but **what is the most proper way of handling this type of scenario**?

**As always, thanks so much for your time and knowledge!**

Comment: dunno about CI, but in general it have to be `htmlspecialchars($value,ENT_QUOTES)`

Comment: why did you tag your question with mysql?

Comment: I guess to denote that I am inserting into a mysql database as I'd imagine that the escaping syntax can be different across various database languages.

Comment: you are inserting your data into HTML form, not database.

Comment: I've removed the tag. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to use the `html_escape()` CodeIgniter function:

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/common_functions.html?highlight=html_escape#html_escape

It's basically just a shortcut for the htmlspecialchars PHP function.

Answer (score 0):

> Add This Function in custom helper file

```
function escape_output($string)
{
    $newString = str_replace('\r\n','<br/>',$string);
    $newString = str_replace('\n\r','<br/>',$newString);
    $newString = str_replace('\r','<br/>',$newString);
    $newString = str_replace('\n','<br/>',$newString);
    $newString = str_replace('\'','',$newString);
    return $newString;
}
```

> Call function in view

```
<?php echo escape_output('Your escaped string here'); ?>
```